# Push local PostgreSQL database to remote Heroku server

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, heroku, environment-variables

On windows 7, I want to push my local PostgreSQL database(9.4.0) to remote PostgreSQL server on Heroku(9.3.3), I followed the [Heroku PostgreSQL Document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) to push:

```
>heroku pg:push postgres HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_NAVY_URL --app salty-atoll-4222

Your version of git is 1.9.5.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Password:
 !    WARNING: Extensions in newly created target database differ from existing source database.
 !
 !    Target extensions:
 !     extname
 !    ---------
 !     plpgsql
 !    (1 row)
 !
 !
 !    Source extensions:
 !      extname
 !    -----------
 !     adminpack
 !     plpgsql
 !    (2 rows)
 !
 !
 !    HINT: You should review output to ensure that any errors
 !    ignored are acceptable - entire tables may have been missed, where a dependency
 !    could not be resolved. You may need to to install a postgresql-contrib package
 !    and retry.
```

My local database server URL is `localhost:5432`. Both the username and database name are `postgres`, and I've add `PGUSER` and `PGPASSWORD` to my system variable, also, my `DATABASE_URL` system variable is `postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres`.

Also, since it says `'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`, I guess `set` command can be use to replace `env`, so I also added a alias `env.bat` in `C:\Windows\System32\env.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
set
```

But it still can't recognized `env` command and my `PGPASSWORD` variable, asks me to type my password by hand, shows the same warning and my database can't be pushed to this remote server. What's the problem here?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I too am having almost exactly the same problems, and am also on Windows 7.  Sure wish someone had an answer ...

Comment: I could see that `heroku-toolbelt.exe` adds to list of system environment variables the variable `HerokuPath` with value `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku` and appends to system environment variable `PATH` the folder paths `C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd` on installation of *Heroku*. This modification on system environment variables is not undone on uninstalling *Heroku*. Are the environment variables `HerokuPath` and `PATH` defined on your machine in same way with correct paths?

Comment: I don't think you need the remote URL, just the name; heroku should resolve that for you. Additionally, can you confirm that the push didn't work? I.e., missing tables/data in the target. It's not clear from the question that the issue is whether the data is missing, or if you are confused by the messages (which indicate a warning, but not an error, by my reading).

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the `ENV` variables need to be configured differently on Heroku, I don't see in your question if you tried this already:

```
heroku config:set GITHUB_USERNAME=joesmith
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v12
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith

$ heroku config
GITHUB_USERNAME: joesmith
OTHER_VAR:    production

$ heroku config:get GITHUB_USERNAME
joesmith

$ heroku config:unset GITHUB_USERNAME
Unsetting GITHUB_USERNAME and restarting myapp... done, v13
```

More related documentation can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application).

Comment: @user3684014 did you tried this, and does the error stays the same? Thanks!